# comparing two cells in two different excel sheets and return difference between corresponding third and fourth cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to compare two cells in two different excel sheets and if they match extract the difference between their corresponding third and fourth columns

Comment: You can try to use IF and COUNTIF functions.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It's not entirely clear what you want to do. I suggest adding some example data to your question and showing what results you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming :

to compare two cells in two different excel sheets (is `A1` & `B1`) and if they match extract the difference between their corresponding third and fourth columns (is `C1` & `D1`) .

use :
`=if(A1=B1,if((C1-D1)>0,(C1-D1),(D1-C1)),"")`

by replacing the A1/B1/C1/D1 with your intended cell address.